# Telethon Bot Как узнать id человека которое фигуриркет в реплае

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Пишу бота для Telegram'a Встал вопрос о реализации функции типа +rep. Например: Есть два тела я и некий Bomzh, я хочу поднять ему репутацию, делаю реплай на любое его сообщение, в этом реплае пишу +rep. Бот распознает, что я выделил конкретно Bomzh и добавляет ему 1 репутацию.

Из сообщения мы можем получить только id сообщения, которое было упомянуто, но не id человека.
Пока единственным костылём видится только сохранение всей истории чата в формате id сообщения - id отправителя, поскольку telgram bot api не дает ботам использовать запросы типа GetMessageHistory и тп.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если открыть [документацию](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message), то много интересного можно найти. В Вашем случае то, что у объекта `Message` есть атрибут `reply_to_message`, и из него можно вытащить ID пользователя, на чьё сообщение мы ответили.

Пример для библиотеки pyTelegramBotAPI и aiogram:

```py
replied_user_id = message.reply_to_message.from_user.id
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, немного не то, но на правильный ответ навело. Покапался немного в структуре Message telethon'a, нашел там _reply_message, от него накопал то что нужно. Поскольку я пользуюсь телетоном тут немного другие правила получаем сообщение через `await event.get_reply_message()` и применяем к нему два метода `.from_id.user_id`, вуаля